# Is this HVAC design incorrect?

Tags: heating-systems, hvac, cooling

Pic for reference - any HVAC pros around?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMIGR.jpg

The return duct matches the supply duct width, but the intake drop looks so small in comparison. Do I need to get this fixed with a larger intake drop? Do I measure the temperature difference through the black canvas with a thermometer to check for oxygen starvation?

Can this system perform well 'by design' ?

Answer (score 1):

### It's fine

More than likely the outlet sizing is just to match the size of the furnace or evaporator.  That's about what mine looks like.  The outlet is just oversized because you typically attach a ton of ducts right to it so having it big helps.  And having over-sized ducts only helps you in the supply line.

Now you should expect the return ducts to be slightly larger than the supply ducts since the pressure is lower for the return.